# PhpStorm: Should I add Xdebug settings to BOTH my php.ini files?

Tags: php, phpstorm, xdebug

In setting up Xdebug in PhpStorm, the CLI interpreter shows the php.ini file for the command line PHP stuff at `/etc/php/7.2/cli/php.ini`.

**Question**: Do I need to add xdebug configs to this CLI version as well?

If so, why? Is it possibly for unit testing, etc?

I ask because I know that the php.ini file at: `/etc/php/7.2/apache2/php.ini` -which ***does*** have Xdebug settings *(see below)* - is the php.ini that handles all my web stuff. Please advise.

Thanks

### My Xdebug Settings

```
[xDebug]
; Debug Settings
zend_extension=/usr/lib/php/20170718/xdebug.so
xdebug.remote_enable = On
xdebug.remote_autostart = Off
;xdebug.remote_host = "localhost"
xdebug.remote_connect_back = On
xdebug.remote_port = 9000
xdebug.idekey = "PHPSTORM"
```

Comment: If you plan to debug PHPUnit tests or other CLI stuff -- you may consider enabling xdebug for CLI as well. Note that current versions of PhpStorm have separate field for specifying Xdebug extension that allow loading Xdebug only when debugging (for CLI only, of course; https://www.jetbrains.com/help/phpstorm/configuring-local-interpreter.html)

Comment: So no need (other than those use cases), thanks. Why not move comment to an answer, so i can credit you. Thanks!